# How do I call a member function from another file in python

Tags: python

I am trying to create a multi-file environment for my project. The File structure is as such

```
project_folder
   |- FileA.py
   |- FileB.py
```

The `FileA.py` has mainly the script in it and also I have improted *FileB* here
**FileA.py**

```
import os,sys
from FileB import temp_class as T

// lines of code 
str = "somestring"
A, B, C = T.func(str)

// lines of code
```

**FileB.py**

```
import os,sys

class temp_class:
    def func(self, S):
        //lines of code
        return (someA,someB,someC)
```

But I am getting the error as

> TypeError: unbound method func() must be called with temp_class instance as first argument (got str instance instead)

Comment: @shay's if you don't want to instantiate the class, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30556857/creating-a-static-class-with-no-instances

Comment: "Unbound method"? If you are using ancient Python 2.x, all you classes should inherit from "object" as well - otherwise you will get really hard to debug things going on. 
But the advice would be to just upgrade to Python 3, of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to instantiate it: `T_inst = T()`, and then use `T_inst.func()`.

To expand: the error message tells you that it expects to find an instance of T (temp_class) as its first argument. When you call a method of a class instance, that very instance is passed as the first argument (usually called "`self`"). In this case you tried to invoke it as a method of the class itself (like a *static method*) so this doesn't happen, and `self` instead was assigned the string that you passed (with the second argument getting `None` instead of a string).

If you don't want to instantiate the class then you could either declare `func` a [static method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735975/static-methods-in-python) (or [in the docs here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#staticmethod)) of `temp_class`, or simply make `temp_class` a module instead of a class (i.e, define its "methods" outside of any class, with the hierarchical structure provided by the way you structure your modules; in your case, to obtain behavior identical to that which you seem to be going for: a directory called `FileB` [that contains a `__init__.py`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages) file (to make it function as a module) and a `temp_class.py` file with the function `func` defined within it).

Answer (score 1):

Since function `func` is in a class called `temp_class`, it has `self` as the first argument, which expects a class instance. You need to call it as `T().func(str)` to resolve this. Basically you need to instantiate the class using `T()` and use that instance to call `func`.

Answer (score 1):

the error message you are seeing , is telling you that you are trying to call "func" method of the "temp-class" without creating an instance of the class ,first in python instance methods need to be called on an instance of the class not in the class itself.
what i recommend is to edit the FileA.py:

```
import os, sys
from FileB import temp_class as T

inct_object = T()  # Create an instance of the temp_class
str = "loremloremlorem"
A, B, C = inct_object.func(str)
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to all the good responses above, please take into account that the file which contains the function definitions and the file calling the functions **must be in the same directory.**